# Gulp - How to re-position my file and sub folders up 1 directory while zipping?

Tags: gulp

Here is my challenge...within my gulpfile.js file I have the following `package` path which I am using to package assets into a specific 'dest' location...

```js
const paths = {

   //...other paths

    package: {
        src: ['**/*', 'public{,/**}', '!.vscode', '!node_modules{,/**}', '!src{,/**}', '!package-lock.json', '!src/views/**/_arc{,/**}', '!gulpfile.js', '!package.json', '!webpack.config.js','!webpack.config.prod.js'],
        dest: 'packaged'
    }
};
```

...via a zip file process like so....

```js
const info = require('./package.json');

//PROCESS PACKAGE
function genPackage(done) {

    //GET CURRENT DATE TO APPEND TO ZIP PACKAGES
    let cdate = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10);

    return src(paths.package.src)
        .pipe((gzip(`${info.name}-${cdate}.zip`)))
        .pipe(dest(paths.package.dest));
    done();
}
```

The above code will produce **package/my-project-2023-06-27.zip** when I run **npm run package** from the terminal.

My `public/` directory in my main project (on either **npm start** or **npm run build**), has an index.htm file with 3 sub folders (css | images | js).

When I run my `npm run package` command from the terminal, I don't want my my-project-2023-06-27.zip to to have the **public/** folder at the root of the zip file. **Instead, when I open my zip file I want to see just that... an index.html file, with 3 sub folders.** Not a public/ folder which I have to click into.

Is there a way for me to implement this adjustment as I am zipping these files up via gulp?

I tried using the **gulp-flatten** package.  I was hoping it would allow me to remove the `public/` folder from my zip file, and keep all the child stuff as they are, this way I can see index.html, css/, images/ js/, but no luck with that yet...

Comment: I tested the answer before seeing you tried using `gulp-flatten`!  It does work with the indicated options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A library like [gulp-flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten) can modify the folder paths of the files in the pipeline.

```js
const flatten = require('gulp-flatten');

 //PROCESS PACKAGE
function genPackage(done) {

  //GET CURRENT DATE TO APPEND TO ZIP PACKAGES
  let cdate = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);

  return gulp.src(paths.package.src)

      .pipe(flatten({ subPath: [1]}))          // add this before your gzip call
      .pipe((gzip(`${info.name}-${cdate}.zip`)))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.package.dest));
  done();
}
```

`flatten({ subPath: [1]})` will remove one folder from the beginning of all the files/folders.  So it gets rid of the `public` folder.

Comment: ha! I thought I tried that! But upon your testing it works!  Many many thanks!